# Save custom ManyToMany form on post django views

Tags: django

I'm biulding custom form with ManyToMany field

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Module(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "module"
        verbose_name = "Module"
        verbose_name_plural = "Modules"

    module_title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Module title",
        max_length=200,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    module_menu_item = models.ManyToManyField(
        'mega_admin.MenuItem',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
module_menu_item = request.POST.getlist('menu_item_menu', '')
save_module_form = ModuleForm(request.POST)

if save_module_form.is_valid():
    module = save_module_form.save(commit=False)
    module.module_title = module_title
    module.module_menu_item = module_menu_item
    save_module_form.save()
```

This way I can successfuly add new module, however none *module_menu_item* are being created.

on **POST** values are:

```
module_menu_item_id {…}
0   28
1   22
2   27
3   25
```

So on one post, needs to be created more than one relation for module and menu item

*NOTE: I don't use default model based form in template*

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `save_m2m` method to save related items also:

```
if save_module_form.is_valid():
    module = save_module_form.save(commit=False)
    module.module_title = module_title
    module.module_menu_item = module_menu_item
    module.save()
    save_module_form.save_m2m()
```

See details in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).